# Windows Server 2016 Active Directory-Detached Cluster - Cannot add a Client Access Point

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, windows-clustering

I am setting up a Windows Server 2016 cluster detached from an active directory (so called Workgroup Cluster, i.e. nodes are not added to an active directory). I cannot add a Client Access Point to the cluster. The error is `Unable to determine if the computer 'client_access_point_name' exists in the domain 'WORKGROUP'.`

How a client access point can be added to the cluster?

P.S.: I need to add a client access point to use it later in SQL Server Availability Group Listener, to use it for auto-failover between mirrors.

Comment: you may get better responses for this on dba.se,also try to tag generalized tag like sqlserver along with version for more visibilty

Comment: thanks, the solution was found at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176198/windows-server-2016-active-directory-detached-cluster-cannot-add-a-client-acce

Comment: glad it helped you